# MediaWiki Page Title Lowercase $wgCapitalLinks = false not working

Tags: mediawiki

I am having trouble to set all page title in lowercase.

I have added `$wgCapitalLinks = false;` but still not working. Please help me.

Comment: I'm not recommend to do it (`$wgCapitalLinks = false;`). It's not how MediaWiki works.

Comment: That what to do? In fact I have replace css text-transform to none problem resolved but what about the config variable?

Comment: Wait, you need to change title in url (like `http://mediawiki/wiki/page` instead `http://mediawiki/wiki/Page`), or in `<title>` and `<h1>`? What's your goal?

Comment: I want to change the page title <h1> .

Answer (score 1):

Try this (add to `LocalSettings.php`):

```
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = 'fnSetTitle';

function fnSetTitle(&$out, &$sk) {
  $out->mPagetitle = strtolower($out->mPagetitle);
  return true;
}
```